# Using interfaces as function parameters in solidity

Tags: solidity, tokens, addresses, interfaces, function

Is it recommended to use contract interfaces as function parameters in solidity against using address. like...

```js
function doSomething (IERC20 token) external { ... }
```

rather than

```js
function doSomething (address token) external { ... }
```

what are the drawbacks for each, downsides, security loopholes to watch out for etc to look out for?

Thank you all in advance for the answers